# How to dockerize a nuxt project inside Turborepo?

Tags: docker, nuxt.js, turborepo

I slightly modified the example Dockerfile from the [documentation](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/deploying-with-docker):

```
FROM node:lts-alpine AS base
 
FROM base AS builder
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN apk update
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm i -g turbo
COPY . .
RUN turbo prune @rusinas/blogue-app --docker
 
# Add lockfile and package.json's of isolated subworkspace
FROM base AS installer
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN apk update
WORKDIR /app
 
# First install the dependencies (as they change less often)
COPY .gitignore .gitignore
COPY --from=builder /app/out/json/ .
COPY --from=builder /app/out/package-lock.json ./package-lock.json
RUN npm install
 
# Build the project
COPY --from=builder /app/out/full/ .
RUN npx turbo run build --filter=web...
 
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app
 
# Don't run production as root
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nuxtjs
USER nuxtjs
 
COPY --from=installer /app/apps/web/next.config.js .
COPY --from=installer /app/apps/web/package.json .
 
# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=installer --chown=nuxtjs:nodejs /app/apps/web/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=installer --chown=nuxtjs:nodejs /app/apps/web/.next/static ./apps/web/.next/static
COPY --from=installer --chown=nuxtjs:nodejs /app/apps/web/public ./apps/web/public
 
CMD node apps/web/server.js
```

The structure of my monorepo is pretty straighforward:

```
apps
  app
    *nuxt-app*
    Dockerfile
packages
  ui

turbo.json
```

And I am getting this error when I am trying to build the container:

```
 > [client builder 6/6] RUN turbo prune @rusinas/blogue-app --docker:
0.476 Turbo error: could not resolve workspaces: We did not find a package manager specified in your root package.json. Please set the "packageManager" property in your root package.json (https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packagemanager) or run `npx @turbo/codemod add-package-manager` in the root of your monorepo.
```

Outside of the docker, `turbo prune @rusinas/blogue-app --docker` works fine, so it looks like I need to put all the monorepo inside of the Dockerfile somehow, because I don't really get how it will be able to find my ui package for example. But this sounds stupid. What am I doing wrong?